# How to make One button check Uncheck check box when clicked more than once?

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

I want to have one button that check unchecks a check box when clicked more than one time.

I came up with this:

```
 function choseall() {      
        switch (d) {

            case 1:
                document.getElementById('cbconditioning').checked = true
                document.getElementById('cbradio').checked = true
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById('cbconditioning').checked = false
                document.getElementById('cbradio').checked = false
                break;
        }
    }


        <input id="btnchoseall" type="button" value="Chose All" onclick="choseall()" /></tr>
        <input id="cbradio" type="checkbox"/>b. TV Radio (TV, Home Theatre, etc.)</td>
        <input id="cbconditioning" type="checkbox"/>a. Air Conditioning</td>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you'd like?  Do you mean you want the "Choose All" checkbox to check/uncheck the checkboxes?  Meaning when I click it one it checks them all and when I click it again it unchecks them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function choseall(){
    var ischecked = document.getElementById('cbconditioning').checked;
    document.getElementById('cbconditioning').checked = !ischecked;
}
```

Flips the checked state of cbconditioning.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you have more than one checkbox, then using `id` is a wrong choose.  Instead using **`name`** attribute

1) Get all the checkbox element with name `cbconditioning` using the following line.

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("cbconditioning");
```

2)Then using **`length`** property get the no.of checkboxes and iterate as follows

```
function choseall() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("cbconditioning");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName("cbconditioning")[i].checked) {
            document.getElementsByName("cbconditioning")[i].checked = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementsByName("cbconditioning")[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

3) What you need is a **`toggle`** like functionality, which is taken care by the if...else.. statement.

4) There is no use of using **`switch`** in your function

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjjY7/)